# Spring Application returns 404 error for all 3rd paty requests (Working fine When the request comes from same server)

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat7, payumoney

In My Spring Application, I have following

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/payment/pspsyncresponse", method = { RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST })
public String handleSyncResponse(
     final HttpServletRequest request, final HttpServletResponse response, final Model model) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    LOG.info("Payment | GET | Received  synchronous response");
    return "pamentpage";
}
```

On Localhost If I am hitting "localhost:8080/payment/pspsyncresponse", it is calling the controller and printing the log and returns to "paymentpage" jsp

But if the same request sent by some another site it is throwing 404 Error

Ex: While doing payumoney integration we need to pass the "successurl" where it will redirect to our application and we can capture the response. PayuMOney is successfully redirecting to above url with formdata Where i can see in "network" tab in browser. But my application not able to hit that controller.

I belive we need to do some configurations at spring level or tomcat level to accept the 3rd paty request

Can any one help me Where i am missing the context?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you share the URL that is being hit from browsers, you can hide the sensitive information from the url. Might be the case you server is reachable outside your local network.

Comment: Payumoney is doing the POST Request. URL: http://{ipaddress}:8080/{sitedomain}/payment/pspsyncresponse

Comment: I tried in Higher environments Where it is public ip. but still 404 error only

Comment: Try removing {sitedomain} from the "callback url for payU" because your application is not configured like this which i can see from localhost:8080/payment/pspsyncresponse

Comment: Tried but no luck. "http://{ipaddress}:8080/{sitedomain}" it self my home page. "http://{ipaddress}:8080/{sitedomain}" is like context path for my application

Comment: When i hit direclty this url in browser it is hitting the controller but from 3rd paty request "http://localhost:8080/{sitedomain}/payment/pspsyncresponse"